# how to ignore all slicers except date slicer and get count in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I would like to get count of order number and I have multiple slicers which would slice down the value . for one calculation .I would need to ignore all the other slicers except date slicer and get the count of orders.could you please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore all the slicers, you can create a measure using the DAX function ALL. And if you want to ignore all the slicers except one, you can use ALLEXCEPT. Those two function will calculate your count based on all the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a visual that only shows the count you are referring to, there is another way. You can stop slicers from interacting with the visual you want your count to appear on. So, you can select the slicer, go to Format and the click Edit Interactions and clik the circle (None interaction). Do the same for all slicers you don't want to affect the visual with your count.

[image: Interaction none]